# Тут не вопрос по коду, тут спрашивается ваше мнение о будущем

Tags: веб-программирование, разработка-игр

Смотрите, я обучаюсь на web-программиста, но думаю, что одним этим не обойдусь. Подскажите, как вот вы думаете, стоит тратить время? В будущем эта профессия будет еще востребована? Просто сейчас уже есть конструкторы сайтов, а в будущем они могут быть такие, что полностью заменят веб-программистов, лет через 20-25. Тогда мы останемся без работки.

Может, лучше пойти в разработку игр? Они то никогда не устареют.

Или лучше в разработку ПО под мобилки? Просто сейчас телефоны так совершенствуются, что, как мне кажется, под них больше приложений делают даже, чем для ПК, ведь телефоны удобнее, их можно носить с собой. Думаю, что Android/iOS разработка не умрет

Comment: Нужно учиться на программиста конструкторов сайтов. Кто-то же их должен будет делать.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Будущие перспективы программирования?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/73611/%d0%91%d1%83%d0%b4%d1%83%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Основной скилл хорошего программиста  - это быстрая обучаемость, в том числе с нуля чему-то совсем новому.  Технологии меняются, эволюционируют. В любой IT-сфере через 20-25 лет все будет во многом иначе нежели сейчас.

Программист учится постоянно, практически каждый день, это призвание не предполагает застоя. Обучаемый человек относительно легко сменит сферу - фундамент, базовые принципы везде одни и те же по сути.

В играх, в мобильной разработке через десятки лет так же все изменится и те фреймворки, подходы, паттерны, которые вы освоете сейчас, в будущем уже мало пригодятся.

Лучше всего не заглядывать так далеко, писать то, что нравится, стараться больше читать умных книжек по алгоритмам, математическим методам в IT, учиться правильным базовым вещам.